# IndexError: string index out of range during a for loop

Tags: python

#Here's a copy of my code:

```
empty_set = []

height = 10

width = 50
for x in range(height):

    for y in range(width):

        empty_set.append('*')  

for x in range(height):

    for y in range(width):
   
        print(empty_set[y][x], end='') 
    print()
```

#The output is IndexError. Can I ask why, please? I tried to change the variables (y and x) to x-1 etc., but I am still getting this sort of error.

Comment: `empty_set` is 1d, not 2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of access operator `[x][y]`:

```
empty_set = []

height = 10

width = 50
for x in range(height):
  empty_set.append([])
  for y in range(width):
      empty_set[x].append('*')  

for x in range(height):
    for y in range(width):
        print(empty_set[x][y], end='') 
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
**************************************************
```